# How to Read CMD output results line by line in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, batch-file, cmd

I want to open the .bat file and for that i am using cmd and and gave input for arguments and at the end i receive whole output results but i want to get just last command output results so please guide me if anyone have any solution.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        private static StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
        private static System.Diagnostics.Process standalone = new System.Diagnostics.Process();

        static void Main()
        {
            StartStandalone();
            StartProcess();
        }

        private static void StartProcess()
        {
            try
            {
                Process process = new Process();
                process.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
                process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
                process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
                process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                process.Start();

                process.StandardInput.WriteLine("C:\\Users\\aali\\EAP-7.2.0\\bin\\Jboss-cli.bat");
                process.StandardInput.WriteLine("connect");
                process.StandardInput.WriteLine("deployment-info");
                process.StandardInput.Flush();
                process.StandardInput.Close();

                String output = "";
                while (!process.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
                {
                    string line = process.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
                    if (line.Contains("RUNTIME-NAME"))
                    {
                        output += line + "\r\n" + process.StandardOutput.ReadLine() + "\r\n";
                    }

                }

                Console.WriteLine(output);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception Occurred :{0},{1}", ex.Message, ex.StackTrace.ToString());
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }

        private static void StartStandalone()
        {
            standalone.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\Users\\aali\\EAP-7.2.0\\bin\\standalone.bat";
            standalone.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

Code that i am using for this task are attached above

Comment: To get the last line you can use Indexof("\n") and then use SubString(index) to read from the last return to end of file.  Most likely the bat file output ends with a return so you need to get the second to last return.

Comment: `i want to get just last command output results` you'll have to write the code for this. A process's output is a character stream, not an array or list of lines. There many not even be any newline characters, or the application may delay before emitting a newline. [Process.StandardOutput](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput?view=net-5.0) is a StreamWriter on top of the process's output which allows you to read the text line by line. If the process delays sending a newline, `ReadLine` will block

Comment: You may be able to use the [OutputDataReceived](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.outputdatareceived?view=net-5.0) event to retrieve lines as they're received and only keep the latest one.

Answer (score 1):

You are already reading each line within your loop, so a simple solution would be to just assign each line to a variable called lastLine and do nothing with this variable until the loop has completed.

Of course, this isn't very efficient but will require minimal changes in your code.

```
string lastLine = "";

while (!process.StandardOutput.EndOfStream) 
{
    lastLine = process.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
}

//lastLine will now contain the value of the last line of the output
Console.WriteLine($"Last Line = {lastLine}");
```